# How to make bar graph shorter for higher numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I would like to inverse the bar graph in a way that the lower the number, the higher the bargraph should be.

Currently in the picture below, those items ranked 200 have the highest bar height while #1 ranked bars are almost invisible.

**Is there a way to draw the graph as an inverse of ranking numbers?**

[image]

Comment: Consider a pie chart or stacked bar chart instead - it would give the ranking visually while retaining the data values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screenshot and solution:

[image]

Comment: Man did I over-complicate the solution... Well done. The only change I would suggest is changing the 'Minimum' value to 1.

Answer (score 2):

You could just make a formula that says something like `max number - current number` to invert them manually, then plot that.

Comment: So far, I tried this but I cannot seem to change the Y-axis plot amount. I would like to show 1 on the top and 200 on the bottom on y-axis.  Both Excel 2003/2007 doesn't have an option to modify the numbers...

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider using inverse (1/x, relative size) or negative (-x, orientation) numbers to be plotted?

Comment: Yes, I have tried negation and inversion techniques but since I could not update the Y-axis value, it didn't work out even though inversion worked great.

Comment: The point is, that whatever Y value you need, this should by supplied by your function. You could perhaps post a manually created picture of the plot you want to display...

Answer (score 0):

The top-rated answer here worked for me... sort of. I was trying to do exactly the same thing as the questioner except on a chart of horizontal bars, not a chart of vertical columns. I *should* have been able to accomplish this by:
- selecting "Format Axis" from the Y-axis
- in the pop-up menu, selecting both "Categories in reverse order" and "Horizontal axis crosses: At maximum category"

But this only changed the order in which the data appeared -- it didn't "flip" the values as desires.

The workaround: Convert the chart to a vertical column chart, make the "Categories in reverse order" and "Crosses: at maximum category" selections in the Format Axis pop-up, then convert back to a horizontal bar chart.

Go figure.